# how to put <img> tag in header.php in Wordpress

Tags: image

i have used the following code but it didnt work

/images/ncr.jpg" alt="ncr.com" />

I have pur my image in the images folder of  twentyeleven child theme
can anyone help

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The theme folder URL can be found at `/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven`.
Your header file is actually included at the root level, and as such relative paths won't work.

WordPress provides a function to access your current theme's directory, and as a result you should use this code:

`<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ncr.jpg" alt='ncr.com'>`